# VBA loop to hide particular values in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column in a table and want to hide the rows in it that have a particular string “work1.”

Fyi it's an interactive table so can have different filters applied at a time.

I'm unsure what to change in the vba code to achieve this…

Here is the section of code:

```
Dim c As Range

For Each c In Range (“T:T). Cells
    If c.Value = “Set1” Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If 
Next c
```

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what *"it's an interactive table so can have different filters applied at a time"* means?

Comment: @VBasic2008 the table is linked to slicers (ie columns are filtered)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. You don't want to iterate through the entire T column, in Excel > 2003 its over a million rows! Calculate the Max Rows in a long and only iterate over the used cells.
2. When you run this macro twice, without the `sheet.Rows.Hidden = False` then it won't work because the cells are already hidden. That's the problem with the filtering...

---

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim c As Range
Dim inputRange As Range
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = Application.ActiveSheet
sheet.Rows.Hidden = False

Dim lngMaxRow As Long
lngMaxRow = Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set inputRange = Range("T1:T" & lngMaxRow)
    
For Each c In inputRange
    If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Where would i actually put the condition, ie when value = "Set1"? (si'm very inexperienced with vba!). bummer, i've already 'range' equals to a different table, that is part of the code before and after i envisioned this section of code to be inserted. Really appreciate your response! I also almost always have issues when inserting 'activesheet' into code, probably because i'm working with many sheets!

Comment: Just change this line `If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then` to `If c.Value = "Set1" Then`

Comment: Hery Jeremy! Thankyou so much for this. I've been on this all day. With very limited vba knowledge, i have been searching the web for guidance. I appreciate you helping me with this!!!

Comment: i have used the code once and it worked... i actually thought it would be great to use it again in the same vba module (for a separate sheet), although it doesn't seem to 'hide' the column ie do what the previous code did... I had changed the code so that names were not the same (to avoid duplications, as vba didn't like that it was duplicated). Do you have any recommendations around this? These are the changes i made:

Comment: //// Dim c2 As Range

Dim inputRange2 As Range

Set sheet = Application.ActiveSheet

sheet.Rows.Hidden = False

''''

Dim lngMaxRow2 As Long

lngMaxRow2 = Range("U" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set inputRange2 = Range("U1:U" & lngMaxRow2)

''''

For Each c2 In inputRange2

    If c2.Value = "Set4" Then

        c2.EntireRow.Hidden = True

    End If

Next c2 ////

Comment: (just added '2' to each name, so that there wasn't any replication)